# Android: How do I check if the equation is right and shows error message instead of crashing?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I'm trying to create a calculator which is successful in calculating numbers but the problem is it crashes whenever I enter a wrong equation. I need your help on how to prevent the users to enter wrong equations.
Examples of wrong equations

> *1*1, 1**2, 2+++2, 2+2+, etc

Below is the block of codes from `MainActivity.java` I need you guys to help me improve this one

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String stringEq = equation.getText().toString();

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.equals:
            String[] digits = stringEq.split("[0-9]+");
            String[] spChar = stringEq.split("[-+*/]");

            int result = Integer.parseInt(spChar[0]);
            for(int i=1; i<spChar.length; i++){

                if(digits[i].equals("+"))
                    result += Integer.parseInt(spChar[i]);
                else if (digits[i].equals("-"))
                    result -= Integer.parseInt(spChar[i]);
                else if (digits[i].equals("*"))
                    result *= Integer.parseInt(spChar[i]);
                else if (digits[i].equals("/"))
                    result /= Integer.parseInt(spChar[i]);
                else
                    result = 0;

            }
            ans.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            break;
        case R.id.sim:
            Intent act = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(act);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'll also add the `EditText` from the `xml` file maybe some of you need to see it

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/equation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="0123456789+-*/"
    android:maxLength="12"
    android:hint="Enter equation"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just check the first character of input and if it's an operation return displaying an error message ("Please enter a valid equation")?

Comment: @Benitok that's what I was trying to do but I failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your first question : **To Avoid Type Operator for Twice** 
Maybe you should use `onTextChangeListener` to judge user's input

Here is my code.

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

boolean ignore = false;

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

private boolean shouldIgnore(char input) {
    return !(input >= '0' && input <= '9');
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int idx_of_last = s.length() - 1;
    if (!ignore && idx_of_last >= 0) {
        char last = s.charAt(idx_of_last);
        if (shouldIgnore(last)) {
            if (s.length() == 1 || (s.length() > 1 && shouldIgnore(s.charAt(idx_of_last - 1)))) {
                ignore = true;
                s.delete(idx_of_last, idx_of_last + 1); // after this , onTextChanged will be called
                ignore = false;
            } else {
                Log.d("KEY_CHANGE", "Format Right");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("KEY_CHANGE", "Last Is Number");
        }
    }
}

});
```

Comment: I'm a newbie and I'm confused. Where do I place codes something like this?

Comment: OMG it's working. Thank you very much. I've learned something new today

Comment: My pleasure. Nice day

Answer (score 0):

Before using String stringEq for calculation, you should add your validation method to validate stringEq, Such as no two consecutive operators and no operator at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can follow TDD (test driven development). This means write the test cases first and then write the code. You can unit testing frameworks for this.

Initially, it will take time but you will get your equation right. Also, try to use debugging mode and just stop the debugger before you are getting a crash.

This way you can debug at run time and change the equation.